# How do I change the Gutter Width in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I make the gutter width a larger size? I want it 4-5x the current width.

See the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The width is a generated dynamic value, derived from several measurements, directly within VScode. See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=lineNumbersWidth&type=) for an idea what going on there. It is not trivial to change this. You would have to dig into the code yourself and be prepared for ill effects.

There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30795) referencing this SO question, so you might want to contribute your reasoning and/or code submissions there.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings.json file, use the following property to increase or decrease the width of the gutter.

```
"editor.lineDecorationsWidth": 0;
```

I’ve set it to 0 as I don’t like a wide gutter. However, based on my experience, you can use any positive integer to set the width to your liking.