# How to remove gutter area from VS Code from both side

Tags: visual-studio-code

There seems to be some bug in VS Code, I exited ZenMode and can see gutter on both side of VS Code. This is making my coding area small and I am not able to remove it. Can someone please help me here

This happened with me earlier also, I had to reinstall VS Code, But can't do it every now and then. So need a permanent solution.

Please refer to red marked area in image below.

[image: Red marked area]

**Note:** I have tried basic troubleshooting like restarting, removing themes, removing all settings etc.
I also tried solutions mentioned below, but those are not the gutters I am referring to

[How can you disable Gutter Indicators in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969277/how-can-you-disable-gutter-indicators-in-vs-code)

[How do I change the Gutter Width in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957564/how-do-i-change-the-gutter-width-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Edit

Obviously I missunderstood your question. You want to turn off that behaviour when you are **not** in zen mode. 
To do so press <kbd>F1</kbd> and execute the command *View: Toggle Centered Layout*. 
I found the answer in [one of VS Code's issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/57003#issuecomment-415336353).

To turn off the centered layout in zen mode read the original answer.

## Original answer

In your settings turn off the *center layout* for zen mode by unchecking the setting *Zen Mode: Center Layout* or if you prefer the json settings set

```
{
    "zenMode.centerLayout": false
}
```

Now there won't be any space between the activity bar and the first editor tab.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Awesome ```Toggle Centered Layout``` Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot