# Visual Studio Code not showing file changes on left side bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a particularly annoying problem (at least for me): VSCode doesn't show the changes I make to a file like in the following image [image: changes: add - remove - modify]

In the file explore on the left sidebar the file is marked as modified, but when I open the file, no change symbol appears.

However, this only happens for JAVA and XML files, while it works for all other file types.

There is already a question for this problem ([vscode-not-showing-the-changes-made-in-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73293666/vscode-not-showing-the-changes-made-in-a-file)), but there was no answer, and since I can't comment on the question, I had to open another one.

I've already tried restarting and updating VSCode, disabling and re-enabling GIT built-in extensions, but nothing so far.

Any advice? Is there another extension to install or a setting to change?
Thank you

Comment: do you have the same problem using VSC-insiders without any extensions installed

Comment: @rioV8 I just installed it and changes are marked in the correct way. Do you think it's an extension that's causing the problem?

Comment: disable your extensions one by one to see who is the culprit

Comment: I found out that it's the _Git SCM Integration_ extension that highlights the changes on the file. But even after disabling it and re-enabling it, the problem persists. On JAVA files nothing is highlighted, while on the others it is

Comment: disable all installed extensions on your VSC and see if it still is a problem, maybe your Java extension wants to use the gutter space for other decorations.

Comment: Nothing. I also tried the solutions showed in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957564/how-do-i-change-the-gutter-width-in-vs-code), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969277/how-can-you-disable-gutter-indicators-in-vs-code) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61139261/visual-studio-code-git-source-control-gutter-stopped-showing).

I also changed _settings.json_ adding `"git.decorations.enabled": true,"spring.dashboard.enableGutter": "off","git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "always"`, but same result.
Even with all Java extensions disables

Comment: @rioV8 I'm pretty sure it's the bug I dup-voted for and not due to an extension. This dup question has been coming up a lot recently. This is approximately the sixth one I've seen.

Comment: @user the OP has tried VSC-insiders and there the problem is gone for his workspace, So he can use v1.75 or 1.77-insiders

Comment: @rioV8 indeed. as it say in my recent edit to my answer in the dup target, the problem is purportedly fixed in insiders, though some users report the fix not working for them.

Comment: I downgraded to version 1.76.0 and the problem is solved. I will wait for the fix in the next version. Thanks a lot for your help